# sequelize findAll sort order in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm trying to output all object list from database with sequelize as follow and want to get data are sorted out as I added id in where clause.

```
exports.getStaticCompanies = function () {
    return Company.findAll({
        where: {
            id: [46128, 2865, 49569,  1488,   45600,   61991,  1418,  61919,   53326,   61680]
        },
        attributes: ['id', 'logo_version', 'logo_content_type', 'name', 'updated_at']
    });
};
```

But the problem is after rendering, all data are sorted out as follow.

```
46128, 53326, 2865, 1488, 45600, 61680, 49569, 1418, ....
```

As I found, it's neither sorted by id nor name. Please help me how to solve it.

Answer (score 320, accepted):

In sequelize you can easily add order by clauses.

```
exports.getStaticCompanies = function () {
    return Company.findAll({
        where: {
            id: [46128, 2865, 49569,  1488,   45600,   61991,  1418,  61919,   53326,   61680]
        }, 
        // Add order conditions here....
        order: [
            ['id', 'DESC'],
            ['name', 'ASC'],
        ],
        attributes: ['id', 'logo_version', 'logo_content_type', 'name', 'updated_at']
    });
};
```

See how I've added the `order` array of objects?

```
order: [
      ['COLUMN_NAME_EXAMPLE', 'ASC'], // Sorts by COLUMN_NAME_EXAMPLE in ascending order
],
```

Edit:

You might have to order the objects once they've been recieved inside the `.then()` promise. Checkout this question about ordering an array of objects based on a custom order:

[How do I sort an array of objects based on the ordering of another array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755889/how-do-i-sort-an-array-of-objects-based-on-the-ordering-of-another-array)

Comment: I want to order like that by `46128, 2865, 49569,  1488,   45600,   61991,  1418,  61919,   53326,   61680`.

Comment: Hmmm. You won't be able to do that (as far as I know)! You'll have to look into sorting the objects once you've received them in the .then() promise?

Why do you need to order them in this specific range?! Is there a order clause that could maybe do it for you? @ppshein

Comment: I tried to do the same with a table associated with another, It did not worked. How can we do this with association  @james111

Answer (score 13):

If you want to sort data either in Ascending or Descending order based on particular column, using `sequlize js`, use the `order` method of `sequlize` as follows

```
// Will order the specified column by descending order
order: sequelize.literal('column_name order')
e.g. order: sequelize.literal('timestamp DESC')
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are using **MySQL**, you can use `order by FIELD(id, ...)` [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396748/ordering-by-the-order-of-values-in-a-sql-in-clause):

```
Company.findAll({
    where: {id : {$in : companyIds}},
    order: sequelize.literal("FIELD(company.id,"+companyIds.join(',')+")")
})
```

Keep in mind, it might be slow. But should be faster, than manual sorting with JS.

Answer (score 5):

You can accomplish this in a very back-handed way with the following code:

```
exports.getStaticCompanies = function () {
    var ids = [46128, 2865, 49569, 1488, 45600, 61991, 1418, 61919, 53326, 61680]
    return Company.findAll({
        where: {
            id: ids
        },
        attributes: ['id', 'logo_version', 'logo_content_type', 'name', 'updated_at'],
        order: sequelize.literal('(' + ids.map(function(id) {
            return '"Company"."id" = \'' + id + '\'');
        }).join(', ') + ') DESC')
    });
};
```

This is somewhat limited because it's got very bad performance characteristics past a few dozen records, but it's acceptable at the scale you're using.

This will produce a SQL query that looks something like this:

```
[...] ORDER BY ("Company"."id"='46128', "Company"."id"='2865', "Company"."id"='49569', [...])
```

Answer (score 5):

May be a little late but want to mention an approach.
Sorting based on the [46128, 2865, 49569,  1488,   45600,   61991,  1418,  61919,   53326,   61680] can be done using ARRAY_POSITION function of ***postgreSQL***.

```
const arr = [46128, 2865, 49569,  1488,   45600,   61991,  1418,  61919,   53326,   61680];
const ord = [sequelize.literal(`ARRAY_POSITION(ARRAY[${arr}]::integer[], "id")`)];

return Company.findAll({
    where: {
        id: arr
    },
    attributes: ['id', 'logo_version', 'logo_content_type', 'name', 'updated_at'],
    order: ord,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible in [Sequelize's order clause](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/querying/#ordering), because as far as I can tell, those clauses are meant to be binary operations applicable to every element in your list. (This makes sense, too, as it's generally how sorting a list works.)

So, an order clause can do something like order a list by recursing over it asking "which of these 2 elements is older?" Whereas your ordering is not reducible to a binary operation (`compare_bigger(1,2) => 2`) but is just an arbitrary sequence (`2,4,11,2,9,0`).

When I hit this issue with `findAll`, here was my solution (sub in your returned results for `numbers`):

```
var numbers = [2, 20, 23, 9, 53];
var orderIWant = [2, 23, 20, 53, 9];
orderIWant.map(x => { return numbers.find(y => { return y === x })});
```

Which returns `[2, 23, 20, 53, 9]`. I don't think there's a better tradeoff we can make. You could iterate in place over your ordered ids with `findOne`, but then you're doing n queries when 1 will do.

Answer (score 0):

if required, databases order their output by the generic order of values in the order by fields.

if your order is not like this, you may add to the select an order_field, and give it a value based upon the value in id:

```
case 
when id=46128 then 0
when id=2865 then 1
when id=49569 then 2
end as order_field

and order by order_field.
```

if there are lots of values, you may stuff them in their original order in a temporary table with an identity primary key order_field, and inner join your select to that temporary table by your value field, ordering by order_field.

i don't know how to do this in sequelize, but found here answers on how it does things that i needed.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me by using **"" quotes** surrounding the property name.

**For Debugging** You can see what is the query that is getting generated by sequelize and then try to run  it on the particular DB console.

In My Case I was not able to sort the data by last `updatedAt` column

Code Snippet :

```
exports.readAll = (req, res) => {
  console.log("Inside ReadAll Data method");
  let data;
  if (!req.body) {
    data = CompanyModel.findAll({  order: [[sequelize.literal('"updatedAt"'), 'DESC']]});
  } else {
    data = CompanyModel.findAll({  order: [[sequelize.literal('"updatedAt"'), 'DESC']]});
  }
  data
    .then((data) => {
      res.send(
        data
      );
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message: err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving data.",
      });
    });
};
```

SQL Query getting formed in my case :

```
Inside ReadAll Data method

Executing (default): SELECT "company_name", "company_id", "on_record", "createdAt", "updatedAt" FROM "companies" AS "company" ORDER BY "updatedAt" DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Incase anyone is using uuid type, using example by @Agniveer from above but modified

```
const ids = [
'f01a057e-5646-4527-a219-336804317246', 
'ee900087-4910-42b4-a559-06aea7b4e250', 
'b363f116-1fc5-473a-aed7-0ceea9beb14d'
];

const idsFormat = `'${ids.join("','")}'`;

const order = [sequelize.literal(`ARRAY_POSITION(ARRAY[${idsFormat}]::uuid[], "<insert_table_name>"."id")`)];
```