# Sort an array of objects with another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have an array of objects like this and would like to re-order with another array of objects. I have tried using indexOf but am possible confusing my syntax as the array fails to re-order. I have read similar threas but haven't been able to apply those solutions to my problem.  Here is code:

```
    const task = [
       {'title':1.1 , 'description': 'task description here' },
       {'title':1.2 , 'description': 'task description here' },
       {'title':1.3 , 'description': 'task description here' },
       {'title':1.4 , 'description': 'task description here' }
    ];

    var taskSort = [
            {'title':1.2 },
            {'title':1.4 },
            {'title':1.3 },
            {'title':1.1 }
        ];

    task.sort(function(a, b) {
      return taskSort.indexOf(a.title) - taskSort.indexOf(b.title); \\have tried many variations of this line
    });
    console.clear();
    console.log(task);
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you want them to be sorted? What is the condition?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort array of objects by string property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sort an array of objects based on the ordering of another array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755889/how-do-i-sort-an-array-of-objects-based-on-the-ordering-of-another-array)

Comment: You're searching for an element that doesn't exist in the `taskSort`. Try doing `taskSort.map(o => o.title).index(a.title)` and that would return the correct index. Well of course save `taskSort.map(o => o.title)` in a variable so that you're not doing `map` op again and again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not getting the expected outcome because you're checking the index of an int (a.title) in an object array (taskSort). So since there are no elements such as that, `taskSort.indexOf(a.title)` always returns `-1`. The easiest way would be to modify the task sort like that:

```js
var taskSort = [1.2, 1.4, 1.3, 1.1];
```

And everything should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you aren't sorting the values, but rearranging them based on the order specified in another array

Hence, you cannot use the `Array.prototype.sort` logic, but can do the following

```js
var taskSort = [
            {'title':1.2 },
            {'title':1.4 },
            {'title':1.3 },
            {'title':1.1 }
        ];
   var task = [
       {'title':1.1 , 'description': 'task description here' },
       {'title':1.2 , 'description': 'task description here' },
       {'title':1.3 , 'description': 'task description here' },
       {'title':1.4 , 'description': 'task description here' }
    ];
   var sortedTask = taskSort.map(tS => task.find(t => t.title === tS.title))

console.log(sortedTask);
```

Essentially, you are mapping through the taskSort array and creating a new array, where the value is satisfying the condition marked by the value in the taskSort array

Answer (score 1):

You could build an object with the wanted order of `title` and take the delta of the values for sorting.

By taking this approach, you could add value as default, if a `title` value is not know. Then you could move this items to bottom with `Number.MAX_VALUE` or to top with `-Number.MAX_VALUE`, like

```
(order[a] || -Number.MAX_VALUE) - (order[b] || -Number.MAX_VALUE) //   top 
(order[a] || Number.MAX_VALUE) - (order[b] || Number.MAX_VALUE)  // bottom
```

```js
 var task = [{ title: 1.1, description: 'task description here' }, { title: 1.2, description: 'task description here' }, { title: 1.3, description: 'task description here' }, { title: 1.4, description: 'task description here' }];
    taskSort = [ { title: 1.2 }, { title: 1.4 }, { title: 1.3 }, { title: 1.1 }],
    order = Object.fromEntries(taskSort.map(({ title }, i) => [title, i + 1]));

task.sort(({ title: a }, { title: b }) => order[a] - order[b]);

console.log(task);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is actually very close, I think you just need to use findIndex instead of indexOf like:

```
return taskSort.findIndex(element => element.title === a.title) - taskSort.findIndex(element => element.title === b.title);
```

indexOf tries to match your input with an exact element of the array, not with a property of an element.