# JS sort array of objets by specific string property (not ascending or descending)

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

do you know if there is a way to sort an array of objects using the sort() method for a specific property? In my case I'd like to sort my array first for "bananas", then for "pears", and then the rest.

```
const initialData = [
{ name: "strawberries", value: 12 },
{ name: "bananas", value: 3 },
{ name: "pears", value: 8 },
{ name: "pears", value: 7 },
{ name: "bananas", value: 10 },
{ name: "apples", value: 6 },
{ name: "bananas", value: 13 },
{ name: "bananas", value: 5 }
]
```

This is how I'd like the sorted data to look like:

```
const sortedData = [
{ name: "bananas", value: 3 },
{ name: "bananas", value: 10 },
{ name: "bananas", value: 13 },
{ name: "bananas", value: 5 },
{ name: "pears", value: 8 },
{ name: "pears", value: 7 },
{ name: "strawberries", value: 12 },
{ name: "apples", value: 6 }
]
```

I know that this function would sort my data ascending or descending:

```
initialData.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (a.name < b.name) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a.name > b.name) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
});
```

Comment: Just add more conditions that test *first* for other conditions that would return -1, 1, or 0.

Comment: Make an array of the values you expect, in the appropriate order, then use [How do I sort an array of objects based on the ordering of another array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9755889/215552) or [JavaScript - sorting an array of IDs based on another array of IDS that is a subset of it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65675712/215552)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could take an object with the wanted order and take a large value as default for sorting.

```js
const
    data = [{ name: "strawberries", value: 12 }, { name: "bananas", value: 3 }, { name: "pears", value: 8 }, { name: "pears", value: 7 }, { name: "bananas", value: 10 }, { name: "apples", value: 6 }, { name: "bananas", value: 13 }, { name: "bananas", value: 5 }],
    order = { bananas: 1, pears: 2 };

data.sort((a, b) => (order[a.name] || Number.MAX_VALUE) - (order[b.name] || Number.MAX_VALUE));

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use an auxiliary array to define the sorting scheme. Here is an example:

```
const sortingScheme = [
  "bananas",
  "pears",
  "strawberries",
  "apples"
]

initialData.sort((a, b) => {
  const indexOfa = sortingScheme.indexOf(a.name);
  const indexOfb = sortingScheme.indexOf(b.name);
  if (indexOfa > indexOfb)
    return 1
  if (indexOfa < indexOfb)
    return -1
  return 0;
})
```

This only works if you know all the names the array can hold. If you are interested in ordering only a few fields you can do this:

```
const orderedScheme = [
  "bananas",
  "pears"
]

initialData.sort((a, b) => {
  let indexOfa = orderedScheme.indexOf(a.name);
  let indexOfb = orderedScheme.indexOf(b.name);

  if (indexOfa < 0) indexOfa = orderedScheme.length;
  if (indexOfb < 0) indexOfb = orderedScheme.length;

  if (indexOfa > indexOfb)
    return 1
  if (indexOfa < indexOfb)
    return -1
  return 0;
})
```

This is because if the element is not contained in the 'sortingScheme' array, the indexOf() function returns -1 which would place the element at the beginning of the array.

I hope I have been useful to you!

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use This For Custom Sorting:

```
initialData.sort(function(a, b) {
  var customSort="bpsacdefghijklmnoqrtuvwxyz";
  var aa=customSort.indexOf(a.substr(0,1));
  var bb=customSort.indexOf(b.substr(0,1));
  if (aa < bb) {
    return -1;
  }else if (aa > bb) {
    return 1;
  }else
    return 0;
});
```

Sorting Performs According to This Characters:

> var customSort="bpsacdefghijklmnoqrtuvwxyz";

Answer (score 0):

sort method, check for names. when names are equal order by value. When names not equal then order by names. (check inline comments)

```js
const initialData = [
  { name: "strawberries", value: 12 },
  { name: "bananas", value: 3 },
  { name: "pears", value: 8 },
  { name: "pears", value: 7 },
  { name: "bananas", value: 10 },
  { name: "apples", value: 6 },
  { name: "bananas", value: 13 },
  { name: "bananas", value: 5 },
];

initialData.sort((a, b) => {
  const order = ["pears", "bananas"]; // high priority items towards end.
  if (a.name === b.name && order.includes(a.name)) {
    return a.value - b.value;
  } else {
    // when item not in order, indexOf will return -1. 
    // Basically comparing the values -1, 0, 1
    return order.indexOf(b.name) - order.indexOf(a.name);
  }
});

console.log(initialData);
```

Answer (score -1):

you can to this

```js
const initialData = [
    { name: "strawberries", value: 12 },
    { name: "bananas", value: 3 },
    { name: "pears", value: 8 },
    { name: "pears", value: 7 },
    { name: "bananas", value: 10 },
    { name: "apples", value: 6 },
    { name: "bananas", value: 13 },
    { name: "bananas", value: 5 }
    ]

    const data = initialData.sort(function(a, b) {
        if (a.name < b.name) {
            if(a.name === "apples") {
                return 1
            }
          return -1;
        }
        return 0;
      });
      console.log(data)
```