# Sort array of objects by string property and also alphabetical

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65688069/8280574) i have sorted my array of objects by a string property. See this example:

```
const preData = [
    { type: "veggie", name: "Tomato salad" },
    { type: "veggie", name: "Cole slaw" },
    { type: "veggie", name: "Nothing" },
    { type: "meat", name: "Spare-ribs" },
    { type: "meat", name: "Steak" },
    { type: "meat", name: "Pulled pork" },
    { type: "potato", name: "Pommes frites" },
    { type: "potato", name: "Curly fries" },
    { type: "potato", name: "King size frites" }
];
```

I tried to sort this by `type` and also by `name`.

```
const sortOrder = { meat: 1, potato: 2, veggie: 3 };

const postData = preData.sort((a, b) => (sortOrder[a.type] || Number.MAX_VALUE) - (sortOrder[b.type] || Number.MAX_VALUE) || (a.name.toUpperCase() > b.name.toUpperCase()));
```

What i expect:

```
postData = [
    { type: "meat", name: "Pulled pork" },
    { type: "meat", name: "Spare-ribs" },
    { type: "meat", name: "Steak" },
    { type: "potato", name: "Curly fries" },
    { type: "potato", name: "King size frites" },
    { type: "potato", name: "Pommes frites" },
    { type: "veggie", name: "Cole slaw" },
    { type: "veggie", name: "Nothing" },
    { type: "veggie", name: "Tomato salad" }
];
```

But the second sort fails. It gets sorted by `type`, but not by `name`.

```
postData = [
    { type: "meat", name: "Spare-ribs" },
    { type: "meat", name: "Steak" },
    { type: "meat", name: "Pulled pork" },
    { type: "potato", name: "Pommes frites" },
    { type: "potato", name: "Curly fries" },
    { type: "potato", name: "King size frites" },
    { type: "veggie", name: "Tomato salad" },
    { type: "veggie", name: "Cole slaw" },
    { type: "veggie", name: "Nothing" }
]
```

I know `||` connects multiple sortings, but why isn't it working here?

Comment: The compare function should return 0 for equal values. Your compare function is wrong. It returns 0 for the second and third element in your input array. Your compare function never returns negative values when names are compared. Reread https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: `preData.sort((a,b) => sortOrder[a.type] - sortOrder[b.type]);`

Comment: btw, an assignment assign the original object reference but not a copy of sorted array.