# How to sort an array of objects by custom order given as a string or array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

Given array:

```
var someAnswers = [
  {
    answer:  'Lyndon Johnson', // answer A
    comment: '...'
  },
  {
    answer:  'Richard Nixon', // answer B
    comment: '...'
  },
  {
    answer:  'Jimmy Carter', // answer C
    comment: '...'
  },
  {
    answer:  'Gerald Ford', // answer D
    comment: '...'
  }
];
```

Some custom order:

```
customOrder = 'A, C, B, D';
```

or

```
customOrder = ['A', 'C', 'B', 'D'];
```

Do something like this:

```
someAnswers.sort(customOrder);
```

Desired result:

```
[
  {
    "answer": "Lyndon Johnson",
    "comment": "..."
  },
  {
    "answer": "Jimmy Carter",
    "comment": "..."
  },
  {
    "answer": "Richard Nixon",
    "comment": "..."
  },
  {
    "answer": "Gerald Ford",
    "comment": "..."
  }
]
```

Another custom order:

```
anotherCustomOrder = 'D, B, A, C';
```

or

```
anotherCustomOrder = ['D', 'B', 'A', 'C'];
```

Do something like this:

```
someAnswers.sort(anotherCustomOrder);
```

Desired result:

```
[
  {
    "answer": "Gerald Ford",
    "comment": "..."
  },
  {
    "answer": "Richard Nixon",
    "comment": "..."
  },
  {
    "answer": "Lyndon Johnson",
    "comment": "..."
  },
  {
    "answer": "Jimmy Carter",
    "comment": "..."
  }
]
```

Comment: How are "Gerald Ford" and 'D' associated?

Comment: This is most likely a duplicate of [How do I sort an array of objects based on the ordering of another array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755889/how-do-i-sort-an-array-of-objects-based-on-the-ordering-of-another-array)

Comment: Just because "Gerald Ford" is the fourth answer (and "D" is the fourth letter in the alphabet).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sort an array of objects based on the ordering of another array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755889/how-do-i-sort-an-array-of-objects-based-on-the-ordering-of-another-array)

Comment: Not really. Because there are IDs which I don't have.

Answer (score 1):

```js
    const sorting = (currentArray, indexArr) => {
        const reArrangedArr = [];
        const deepCopied = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(currentArray));
        indexArr.forEach(index => reArrangedArr.push(deepCopied[index]));
        return reArrangedArr;
    }
    var someAnswers = [
      {
        answer:  'Lyndon Johnson', // answer A
        comment: '...'
      },
      {
        answer:  'Richard Nixon', // answer B
        comment: '...'
      },
      {
        answer:  'Jimmy Carter', // answer C
        comment: '...'
      },
      {
        answer:  'Gerald Ford', // answer D
        comment: '...'
      }
    ];
    console.log(sorting(someAnswers, [3,0,1,2]))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you were willing to replace the letters with numbers in customOrder, you could do something like this:

```
customOrder = [0, 2, 1, 3];

sort(someAnswers, customOrder) {
    res = [];
    customOrder.forEach((n) => {
        res.push(someAnswers[n]);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Alternatively, if you really want to use letters:

```
customOrder = ["A", "C", "B", "D"];

sort(someAnswers, customOrder) {
    res = [];
    customOrder.forEach((n) => {
        res.push(someAnswers[n.charCodeAt(0) - 65]);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Could you add a working snippet?

Comment: A working snippet would be appreciated. At least there is missing `);`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an object with the indexes according to the desired order, and then use the function `Array.prototype.map` and extract the values by using the previously created indexes array.

```js
const someAnswers = [  {    answer:  'Lyndon Johnson', comment: '...'  },  {    answer:  'Richard Nixon',    comment: '...'  },  {    answer:  'Jimmy Carter',     comment: '...'  },  {    answer:  'Gerald Ford',    comment: '...'  }],
      answerIndexes = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'].reduce((a, c, i) => ({...a, [c]: i}), {}),
      customOrder = ['A', 'C', 'B', 'D'],
      sorted = customOrder.map(L => someAnswers[answerIndexes[L]]);

console.log(sorted);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you explain the part where the magic happens (`reduce((a, c, i) => ({...a, [c]: i}), {})`) and the `L` in `map()`?